string called 'undefined' while parsing child_process data
I've this electron code:
ipcMain.handle('ping', async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const shiinobiPath = join(__dirname, "../../resources/shiinobi/shiinobi")
    // const args = ['get-specific-staff-information', '1']
    const args = ['get-staff-urls']

    const process = spawn(shiinobiPath, args)

    let output: string

    process.stdout.on('data', (data: Buffer) => {
      output += data.toString()
    })

    process.stderr.on('data', (data: Buffer) => {
      console.error("Err: ", data.toString())
    })

    process.on('close', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        try {
          const parsedJson = JSON.stringify(output)
          resolve(parsedJson)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(output)
          console.error("JSONError: ", err)
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Process exited with code: ", code)
        reject(new Error("Process exited with code: " + code))
      }
    })

    process.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("Process err: ", err)
      reject(err)
    })
  })
})

here:
const parsedJson = JSON.stringify(output)

i wanted to use JSON.parse instead, but the output seems invalid, like:
"undefined{\"1\": \"https://myanimelist.net/people/1/Tomokazu_Seki\", \"2\": \"https://myanimelist.net/people/2/Tomokazu_Sugita\", \"3\": \"https://myanimelist.net/people/3/Satsuki_Yukino\", \"4\": ...
...

see that undefined string at the start?
but when i run that shiinobi on terminal, it returns everything fine (no issues).
I checked shiinobi cli output, but everything is fine on that part.
and i tried parsing each chunks, that was raising invalid JSON error.

Try putting output = ""; directly after declaring it, i.e. after let output: string. This should initialise the variable and could cause the undefined to go away (since you're only adding to output when receiving data).
